# Let X and Y be metric spaces, with X compact, and let f be a function from X to Y be a continuous map that that is surjective.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let X and Y be metric spaces, with X compact, and let f be a function from X to Y be a continuous map that that is surjective. 
Prove that Y is compact with respect to open coverings, and convergent subsequences.

I have no idea how to even begin this proof. I have some knowledge how to prove that Y is compact but I am confused how to approach the question with respect to open coverings and subsequences. Can anyone assist me please?

Comment: You need to proof two statements: 1. Every covering of $Y$ has a finite sub-cover and 2. Every sequence in $Y$ has a convergence sub-sequence. If we focus on $1$, given a covering of $Y$ can you construct a covering for $X$?

Comment: Yes i can! Thanks for the asistance everyone! I needed this to start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take an open cover for $Y$ consisting of sets $\{ O_{\alpha} \}$. Find the inverse image of each set $O_{\alpha}$, which must be open by the continuity of $f$. The inverse images constitute an open cover of $X$. Then as $X$ is compact there exists a finite subcover of it. The image of the finite subcover is a finite subcover of $\{ O_{\alpha} \}$ and hence $Y$ is compact.

These are your guidelines, now just fill in the details and you have a proof.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to sequences: if $(y_n)$ is some sequence in $Y$ by surjectiveness we can find $x_n \in X$ with $f(x_n) = y_n$. Now use that in $X$ sequences have convergent subsequences and then use that $f$ preserves limits of (sub)sequences, being continuous.